# How to put title above meta when I render a view in Yii 1.1

Tags: php, yii

I have a question in view,
I add title and meta by code like below:

```
$this->pageTitle = 'testTitle';
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerMetaTag('testKeyWords','keywords');
```

And i get the result like this:

[image: Example code]

But i want the title above the keyword,how to do ?

Thanks for help!

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Please got through the link on how to ask effective questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text. Copy and paste your code into the question itself. (It's not visible in the question but the image is in the markdown of the post.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At our web development company [HeavyDots](http://heavydots.com/) we've got into this requirement too, specially because we wanted to put SEO related tags first so that Google can find them right at the beginning.

### Basically this is what you need to:

1) Extend the core ClientScript component at framework\web\CClientScript.php

Create the file `protected\components\CustomClientScript.php` and put in the following contents:

```
<?php

/**
 * This class extends framework\web\CClientScript.php 
 * and overrides some of its methods.
 */
class CustomClientScript extends CClientScript {

  /**
   * Inserts the scripts in the head section.
   * @param string $output the output to be inserted with scripts.
   */
  public function renderHead(&$output) {
    $html = '';
    foreach ($this->metaTags as $meta)
      $html .= CHtml::metaTag($meta['content'], null, null, $meta) . "\n";
    foreach ($this->linkTags as $link)
      $html .= CHtml::linkTag(null, null, null, null, $link) . "\n";
    foreach ($this->cssFiles as $url => $media)
      $html .= CHtml::cssFile($url, $media) . "\n";
    foreach ($this->css as $css)
      $html .= CHtml::css($css[0], $css[1]) . "\n";
    if ($this->enableJavaScript) {
      if (isset($this->scriptFiles[self::POS_HEAD])) {
        foreach ($this->scriptFiles[self::POS_HEAD] as $scriptFile)
          $html .= CHtml::scriptFile($scriptFile) . "\n";
      }

      if (isset($this->scripts[self::POS_HEAD]))
        $html .= CHtml::script(implode("\n", $this->scripts[self::POS_HEAD])) . "\n";
    }

    if ($html !== '') {
      $count = 0;
//      $output = preg_replace('/(<title\b[^>]*>|<\\/head\s*>)/is', '<###head###>$1', $output, 1, $count);
      $output = preg_replace('/(<\\/title\s*>)/is', "$1\n<###head###>", $output, 1, $count);
      if ($count)
        $output = str_replace('<###head###>', $html, $output);
      else
        $output = $html . $output;
    }
  }

}
```

2) Change your configuration so that the application will start using it:

Add the new component in your configuration file `protected\config\main.php`:

```
...
// application components
'components' => array(
    ...
    'clientScript' => array(
      'class' => 'application.components.CustomClientScript',
    ),
    ...
```

### Additional notes

#### Extending application components

What we have just done is a very common way of customizing Yii without editing core files and as you see it's easy to implement.

For every application component that you wish to extend just look for the original one in the core files and then make your own.

We've placed this one in `protected\components` but you could have placed it wherever you want if your application is big and you want to have a better organized structure.

As you can see in this component we've overriden the `renderHead` method and changed just one line that dictates where to insert the head-related code.

We've made it save it just after `</title>` to obtain the exact requirement that you have asked for, but as you can guess you could play and change things if you want a different behaviour.

#### What if you already had a custom client script

In many of our projects we were already using a custom client script, for example, the [minScript extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/minscript/).

In this case, in order to keep both we did this:

1) Leave the minScript component in the configuration instead of our custom one

```
'clientScript' => array(
  'class' => 'ext.minScript.components.ExtMinScript',
),
//    'clientScript' => array(
//      'class' => 'application.components.CustomClientScript',
//    ),
```

2) Make minScript component extend from ours

```
//class ExtMinScript extends CClientScript {
class ExtMinScript extends CustomClientScript {
```

Or if you don't want to change minScript code:

1) Autoload the minScript component class by adding this into the `import` section of the configuration:

```
'ext.minScript.components.*',
```

2) Extend your component from minScript component instead of core one

Important: Since minScript also has its own implementation of `renderHead` method in order to keep both you will have to bring the minScript block of code to your component.

```
<?php

/**
 * This class extends framework\web\CClientScript.php 
 * and overrides some of its methods.
 */
class CustomClientScript extends ExtMinScript {

  /**
   * Inserts the scripts in the head section.
   * @param string $output the output to be inserted with scripts.
   */
  public function renderHead(&$output) {

    // minScript block
    $this -> _minScriptProcessor('scripts', self::POS_HEAD);
    $this -> _minScriptProcessor('css');
    // end minScript block

    $html = '';
    foreach ($this->metaTags as $meta)
      $html .= CHtml::metaTag($meta['content'], null, null, $meta) . "\n";
    foreach ($this->linkTags as $link)
      $html .= CHtml::linkTag(null, null, null, null, $link) . "\n";
    foreach ($this->cssFiles as $url => $media)
      $html .= CHtml::cssFile($url, $media) . "\n";
    foreach ($this->css as $css)
      $html .= CHtml::css($css[0], $css[1]) . "\n";
    if ($this->enableJavaScript) {
      if (isset($this->scriptFiles[self::POS_HEAD])) {
        foreach ($this->scriptFiles[self::POS_HEAD] as $scriptFile)
          $html .= CHtml::scriptFile($scriptFile) . "\n";
      }

      if (isset($this->scripts[self::POS_HEAD]))
        $html .= CHtml::script(implode("\n", $this->scripts[self::POS_HEAD])) . "\n";
    }

    if ($html !== '') {
      $count = 0;
//      $output = preg_replace('/(<title\b[^>]*>|<\\/head\s*>)/is', '<###head###>$1', $output, 1, $count);
      $output = preg_replace('/(<\\/title\s*>)/is', "$1\n<###head###>", $output, 1, $count);
      if ($count)
        $output = str_replace('<###head###>', $html, $output);
      else
        $output = $html . $output;
    }
  }

}
```

### Final note

Remember to re-check your implementation if you update Yii or minScript in the future so there are no changes that will break your code.